# Robot Framework Selenium retrieve iframes src attribute and place it in a variable

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, robotframework

I have an iframe element in a webpage, this iframe represents a html document which represents a form I've generated. I want to write an automated Selenium script which validates certain values of this document. I've managed to do so by manually copying the URL in the iframes "src" attribute, then running the Selenium keyword "Go To" on this new URL. From this page I can then browse the html documents DOM as normal (I could not browse within the iframe when it was part of the previous page).

I want to make it slightly more elegant now so the script grabs this "src" attribute and then places it in a variable. In this way I will be able to write an automated script to navigate to a report of any URL, rather than having to manually copy the URL as I've done in this case.

So in my Robot/Selenium script I want to create a variable which retrieves this src attribute from the iframe tag. Let's say in a simple example my iframe has an id of "my_frame" which we used to grab it, and the src is "www.google.com".

Is there a Selenium/robot function I can use to retrieve a particular attribute from a provided element, and return this as a variable?

e.g.

```
${URL} = Set Variable  <Insert code here!>
```

Comment: Why do you need to go to the iframe, rather than just using the iframe that is already on the page? Are you aware of the [select frame](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Frame) keyword?

Comment: I was not aware of this. So I can pass the iframe xpath to Select Frame and then I can access element xpaths from within the frame?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks. My Selenium is still having trouble even locating the iframe though. Without me posting code (not sure on the company policy about that...) could you think of any reason why an iframe within an html document could not be read by Selenium?

Comment: Ok I got it working, just put in a Sleep for 3 seconds line and it all seems to work after that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Get element attribute](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) keyword, which will let you get the `src` attribute.

For example:

```
| | ${src}= | get element attribute | frame1@src
```

However, if all you need is to access elements within the iframe, you can switch to that frame using [Select Frame](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Frame), and then use the selenium keywords directly on the page rather than opening a new page:

There are a few other frame related keywords, such as [frame should contain](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Frame%20Should%20Contain) and [Current frame contains](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Current%20Frame%20Contains), and a few others.

Comment: I found this soon after I posted the question, can't believe I missed it lol. One problem though is Selenium can't seem to find the iframe to grab the src, even with the correct ID/xpath

Comment: I got it working now with Select Frame, just needed to let it sleep for a few seconds!! Thank you!